# no such column: Homepage_goods.number_text

Tags: html, django, django-views

I have a problem of displayed a model text in index.html
This is code of views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text

def number(self):
    return self.number_text
```

This is code of html(index.html)

```
{% for good in goods %}
     <h3 class="numbers">{{good.number_text}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```